# SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xae'

Tags: python

I am using Python in selenium to create scripts. When used the below code getting syntax error. I could find that the issue is with the registered trademark symbol '®' in title. Please help me out of this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('https://advance.lexis.com')
assert 'Lexis Advance® Sign In | LexisNexis' in driver.title
```

Comment: Add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of your question is fine: I inspected it to see that StackOverflow provides the ® symbol encoded as UTF-8.

Based on the error message in the title, Python is reading the file as UTF-8 but I suspect that your editor is using a different encoding to save the file.

Perhaps it is using [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout) (aka 'latin1'), or something else.  ISO 8859-1 defines the byte 0xAE as the registered trademark symbol.  [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf) also defines code point U+00AE as the registered trademark symbol.

You have two solutions:

1. determine what encoding your editor is using and tell python by putting `# encoding: foo` at the top of your file
2. configure your editor to use UTF-8

Comment: Since I am new to python, could you help me to fix this with any one of the solution. Iam using PyCharm to write scripts.

Comment: I use vim (and eclipse).  Maybe [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=pycharm+set+encoding) will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Python 3 and Pydev in Eclipse an alternate solution would be to change the file encoding to utf-8 in the properties as shown below. Just right click on the file, go to properties and change the encoding to utf-8

[utf-encoding pydev (eclipse)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iULYv.png)

Answer (score 0):

That means you are using a character that your editor can't read or accept.   I am writing a secret language program and I used `.replace()` to edit the text.

I used the `❊` character, and I had the same error! But I replaced it with another character, and now I have no problem.